# why prettier.semi not adding any semicolons on my JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, prettier

This one of my files that prettier didn't add any semicolons
but format it well,

```
function usercreate(name,score){
        this.name = name 
        this.score = score
        }
        usercreate.prototype.increment=function(){
            this.score++
            console.log(this.score)
        }
        usercreate.prototype.login=function(){
            console.log("loged in")
        }
    const user1=new usercreate("zahal",100)
    user1.increment()
    user1.login()
    const user2=new usercreate("sam",01)
    user2.increment()
    user2.login()
```

and this is my v-code setting.json

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Light",
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "prettier.semi": true
}
```

and I don't use Eslint

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How I've sorted it after having super huge frustrations with Prettier stopping working in VSCode.

1. Select `VS Code` -> `View` -> `Command Palette`, and type: `Format Document With`
2. Then `Configure Default Formatter`... and then choose `Prettier - Code formatter`.

This sorted the problem for me magically.

Depending on your case this might help you...

Answer (score 6):

go to setting and type word semi it will show this
if it's not checked then checked it and try again
[image]

Comment: Approach works but there are tons of semicolon option in settings so you gotta find the one for your case e.g. optional js/ts semicolon > insert.

Comment: I had the default formatted set up, so accepted answer didn't work for me. I've used this and it worked nicely.

Answer (score 3):

I have just experienced the same problem and none of the solutions detailed above worked for me.

What it worked for me was adding a configuration file to my project.

A simple `.prettierrc` with a JSON and the `semi` property:

```
{
  "semi": true,
 ...
}
```

See more detail here:
https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9M7E.png)

Write these words in the setting search bar and make sure to change the default option to the insert option
I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had Prettier as default formatter. Also in preferences I had `Prettier: semi` enabled.

**BUT** for some reason in `.prettierrc` there was `semi: false`. After change to `semi: true` it was fixed